# Mongoose does not query my collection using .find() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I connected to the collection and then began my query on the collectionto find all documents with this query. However when I log the result I get a Readable object, which I assume is a stream. I used some stream methods on it but it only returns one document. I'm not sure why it doesn't return json.

```
const path = require('path'),
      User = require(path.join(__dirname, '../models/user.js')),
      Card = require(path.join(__dirname, '../models/card.js')),
      mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = {

  get: (req, res) => {
    const foo = mongoose.connection.db.collection('foo');

      Card.find({ _id: {$in: req.user.cards } },
            { name: 1,
              bank: 1 }).exec(function(err, cards) {

        if (err) throw err;


        // Problem: does not return documents or error
        foo.find({ bank: 'chase'}, { name: 1, bank: 1, value: 1 }, function(err, bonus) {
          if (err) throw err;

          console.log(bonus);
        });


      });

  }

}
```

Here is the output. I don't think my query is executing but I don't know where to go from here.

```
Readable {
  pool: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler: 
   { s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: {},
  ns: 'kard_development.kard_bonus',
  cmd: 
   { find: 'kard_development.kard_bonus',
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     query: { bank: 'Chase' },
     slaveOk: false },
  options: 
   { skip: 0,
     limit: 0,
     raw: undefined,
     hint: null,
     timeout: undefined,
     slaveOk: false,
     db: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        s: [Object],
        serverConfig: [Getter],
        bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
        databaseName: [Getter],
        _listening: true },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     disconnectHandler: { s: [Object], length: [Getter] } },
  topology: 
   EventEmitter {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { reconnect: [Function],
        timeout: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Function],
        destroy: [Object],
        serverDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function],
        serverHearbeatFailed: [Function],
        serverOpening: [Function],
        serverClosed: [Function],
        topologyOpening: [Function],
        topologyClosed: [Function],
        topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 14,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     s: 
      { options: [Object],
        callbacks: [Object],
        logger: [Object],
        state: 'connected',
        reconnect: true,
        reconnectTries: 30,
        reconnectInterval: 1000,
        emitError: true,
        currentReconnectRetry: 30,
        ismaster: [Object],
        readPreferenceStrategies: undefined,
        authProviders: [Object],
        id: 0,
        topologyId: -1,
        tag: undefined,
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        monitoring: false,
        haInterval: 10000,
        wireProtocolHandler: [Object],
        Cursor: [Object],
        bsonInstance: {},
        inquireServerStateTimeout: null,
        bson: {},
        pool: [Object],
        isMasterLatencyMS: 8,
        inTopology: false,
        serverDetails: [Object],
        serverDescription: null,
        topologyDescription: null },
     hashedName: '1309e35791f04f1f4fc35d5e683e81d350dd04f4',
     name: [Getter],
     bson: [Getter],
     wireProtocolHandler: [Getter],
     id: [Getter] },
  cursorState: 
   { cursorId: null,
     cmd: 
      { find: 'kard_development.kard_bonus',
        limit: 0,
        skip: 0,
        query: [Object],
        slaveOk: false },
     documents: [],
     cursorIndex: 0,
     dead: false,
     killed: false,
     init: false,
     notified: false,
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     batchSize: 1000,
     currentLimit: 0,
     transforms: undefined },
  callbacks: null,
  logger: { className: 'Cursor' },
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: true,
     highWaterMark: 16,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s: 
   { numberOfRetries: 5,
     tailableRetryInterval: 500,
     currentNumberOfRetries: 5,
     state: 0,
     streamOptions: {},
     bson: {},
     ns: 'kard_development.kard_bonus',
     cmd: 
      { find: 'kard_development.kard_bonus',
        limit: 0,
        skip: 0,
        query: [Object],
        slaveOk: false },
     options: 
      { skip: 0,
        limit: 0,
        raw: undefined,
        hint: null,
        timeout: undefined,
        slaveOk: false,
        db: [Object],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        disconnectHandler: [Object] },
     topology: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 14,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        s: [Object],
        hashedName: '1309e35791f04f1f4fc35d5e683e81d350dd04f4',
        name: [Getter],
        bson: [Getter],
        wireProtocolHandler: [Getter],
        id: [Getter] },
     topologyOptions: 
      { socketOptions: {},
        auto_reconnect: true,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        reconnect: true,
        emitError: true,
        size: 5,
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        bson: {},
        messageHandler: [Function],
        wireProtocolHandler: [Object] },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     currentDoc: null },
  sortValue: undefined }
```

Comment: Note that your first `find` has `.exec()` on the back of it, and your second `find` does not.

Comment: @dvlsg if i write 
`foo.find({ bank: 'chase'}, { name: 1, bank: 1, value: 1 }).exec(function(...));`
=========================================================
the error is:
`TypeError: Uncaught error: foo.find(...).exec is not a function`

Comment: Is that a link directly to the mongodb driver? See if [this](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2c3d141d9ba22e0030690d33984b3dce8a2afd44/README.md#find-all-documents) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Mongoose, it's known as an ODM for MongoDB, which is great if you're using of models/schemas, but for simple queries over a collection its a little weird.  If you look at the Mongoose API http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html, the find methods are only available to **models** and **queries**, which is why your first find works, you are using the Card model.

However if you want to do a query on your collection, like you have in this line:

```
const foo = mongoose.connection.db.collection('foo');
```

It won't quite work as mongoose connection objects don't have a .find() method.  One  thing you can do is use the native MongoDB driver for Node, sort of what @dvlsg was alluding to in the comments, and you'll probably get what you are looking for.